# XML Parsing: counting the number of sub elements

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am very new to XML. I have an XML output like the following,

```
<ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:yahoo:srch" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:srch http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/WebSearchRelatedResponse.xsd">
<Result>london olympics 2012</Result>
<Result>olympics schedule</Result>
<Result>olympics closing ceremony</Result>
<Result>winter olympics</Result>
<Result>nbc olympics</Result>
<Result>2016 olympics</Result>
<Result>olympics opening ceremony</Result>
<Result>special olympics</Result>
<Result>2008 olympics</Result>
<Result>2020 olympics</Result>
</ResultSet>
```

I need to count the number of  tags in the parent tag .

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultSet");
```

The above gives a single element object. How to know how many results are there in this set?

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: Please tag with what language you are parsing in.

Comment: what language are you using? C#?

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to use this in my android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

int count = nl.getLength();

Answer (score 2):

To get the size of the set:

`nl.getLength()`

`public int getLength()`

> The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices
>   is 0 to length-1 inclusive.

[Node List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach is to use XPath to count the # of elements.

```
count(/resultSet/result)
```